# Django-filter filtering foreign model

Tags: python, django, django-filter

i have two models

```
class Sku(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
```

I want that in the filtering appeared only manufacturers associated with the current set of sku.

```
my view part:
 c['skus'] = self.object.skus.filter(hide=False, prices__price_type=PRICE_ROZN).prefetch_related('prices',
                                                                                                        'stock').all().order_by(
            'prices__value')
        sku_filter = SkuFilter(self.request.GET, c['skus'])
```

If Self existed at this moment, I would filter out the manufacturers in this way:

```
class SkuFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # manufacturer__title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')


    manufacturer = django_filters.filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        name='manufacturer',
        to_field_name='title',
        queryset=Manufacturer.objects.filter(
            pk__in=self.queryset.objects.values_list('manufacturer').distinct()),

    )

    class Meta:
        model = Sku
        fields = ['manufacturer', ]
```

But it is obvious that at the given moment the self does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by this method:

1. create field without filttration like (Manufacturer.objects.all())
2. wait for metaclass magic create base_fitler field
3. override **init** and replace current filter

   ```
   class SkuFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

       def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, prefix=None, strict=None):
           self.base_filters['manufacturer'] = django_filters.filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
           name='manufacturer',
           to_field_name='title',
           queryset=Manufacturer.objects.filter(
               pk__in=queryset.values_list('manufacturer').distinct()),
       )
           super().__init__(data, queryset, prefix, strict)

       manufacturer = django_filters.filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
           name='manufacturer',
           to_field_name='title',
           queryset=Manufacturer.objects.all()
       )

       class Meta:
           model = Sku
           fields = ['manufacturer', ]
   ```